# My Images keep going vertical, not horizontal

Tags: jquery, css, image

My images seem to keep going vertical, not horizontal as I would like.
http://jsfiddle.net/MrPsau/3eCKJ/
    `Here's a fiddle.`

Comment: Can you please clarify the question? What do you mean by "vertical" or "horizontal"?

Comment: What order I want the three images to be in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a hard width to your #tabs class:

```
#tabs {
    width: 910px;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/iGanja/3eCKJ/2/

or add a nowrap

```
#tabs {
    white-space: nowrap;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/iGanja/3eCKJ/3/

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the `width` on `#tabLeft`. Your images will then tend to be inline, but if they are too big they will still break onto the next line:

http://jsfiddle.net/3eCKJ/1/